# Not Receiving push notifications from firebase

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I checked my provisioning profiles and all are fine as i used the profiles in a demo provided by firebase, & i am receiving push notifications from that demo project.
Issue is In my main project I am using :

- same code as demo project.
- same provisioning profiles.
- same .plist file.
- same pods with same version.

Still I am not able to receive push notifications in my project. Let me know where is i am missing something.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As you have tried refreshing the certificates and checking that other things are valid, try one more thing. In your info.plist file set

```
FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = YES
```

This worked for me.
[image]

Comment: Had this issue, and make sure your app has "Push Notification" capabilities enabled. One final thing! I had to completely delete the app and re-install it via Xcode before the pushes were received properly.

Answer (score 2):

1-Make sure bundle id is the same

2-Changed the .p12 certificate in firebase

3-Downloaded google-plist in project

Comment: 1. bundle id is same.(infact copied from main project to demo in order to execute it) 2. I used authkey instead of certificates. same at both place. 3. Same plist file is present at both places.

Comment: first distribution or development ? tried sending to one device by copying fcm token and send to single device from firebase dashboard ??

Comment: its development. ya tried to send to my device by getting fcm token. Not receiving the notification in this case too.

Comment: look to project settings in both , make them same and capabilities also check entitlements file

Comment: Yes, all desired capabilities are there. Checked settings entitlements; they consists required things which are working in demo. might be i am missing something,but not able to find that.

Comment: setting the 'FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled' to 'yes' fixed it for me..

Answer (score 2):

Fixed mine by adding this to `AppDelegate`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}
```

I have `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` set to `false`.

<sub>[Source](https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/64)</sub>