# Firebase/APNS Notification not receiving after ios app update

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

We implemented Push notification in our project with Firebase notification. Our current app (which is available in market) is receiving the notification and showing the notification in device (Badge, Alert). When we override the existing application with the new update (With new updated payload), the app getting new "Device Token" and the device not showing the push notification at anytime. Even, the firebase delegates getting called when the app is in foreground.

> 1. We tried the old app Firebase device token in the new update app. We are receiving the push notification perfect.
> 2. We tried the new device token in the new updated app. We are not receiving the push notification at any time. Also, we are receiving
>      two different device tokens.
> 3. Rechecked the "GoogleService-Info.plist" and the configurations are perfect.

Can anyone help on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check it out :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217757/not-receiving-push-notifications-from-firebase

Answer (score 0):

Try to add FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled in your info.plist file.

```
FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = YES
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We tried it but, it didn't help us. Still the device token is differ from the old one. Also, the device not receiving the notification. But, badly delegates getting called when the app is in foreground (Note: System didn't show the notification banner). Any idea? If we use the old token, we are getting notification.