# notifications not received from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

A FCM firebase notification push message was received from the remote message function but does not push on my device. I have set the firebase proxy delegate to yes.

[image: notification error]

Comment: You should include the text of the error message in your post, as well as the code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: Check it out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217757/not-receiving-push-notifications-from-firebase

Answer (score 0):

Rembember that push notification not showing on Simulator and when the app is running, just hide app and try send a new notification.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure certain things.

> 1. You are not testing in a simulator. Notifications are not allowed there.
> 2. Payload used to be proper. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html
> 3. Permission for notification should be given.