# Unable to add push notifications with Firebase to iOS 11 app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried following the tutorial on Firebase's webpage to add Push Notifications to my app. I have done everything with the certificates and such, but I think something is wrong with the code.

My iPhone is not receiving any notifications when I sent them from the Firebase webpage.

What am I missing in my code?

Here is my AppDelegate.swift file:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseInstanceID
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent


        FIRApp.configure()


        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // [END register_for_notifications]


        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.


    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }


}
```

Comment: instead of `completionHandler: {_, _ in })` try logging to see if you're getting any errors... Also show us how you're configuring your payload and tell us about your target settings you've made in the compatibilities. To be sure of the settings I highly recommend you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios/42302369#42302369) as well as you may have missed some settings...

Comment: @Honey I get this error: `Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"`

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/111#issuecomment-251879860) ( I just googled that error. There seems to be lots of other links about it. You might want to edit your question now and tell us based on that error what answers you tried...)

Comment: @Honey I already tried checking Push Notifications on, off and back on, with no result. I also have a Development APNs certificate uploaded to the firebase server

Comment: Ok still edit your question to include the new error and link similar questions. Otherwise it will get closed as a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not Receiving push notifications from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217757/not-receiving-push-notifications-from-firebase)