# Flutter IOS firebase_message only work in firebase console

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

i've developed crossplatform app using flutter with firebase_message plugin.
it works well in android system but push notification does not work in IOS partially

when i try to send push notification from firebase console web to all of IOS devices, it works well

but if i try to send using POST method with

```
<header start> 
Authorization : <Firebase server key> 
<header end>

{
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "priority" : "high",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "bd",
     "title": "tt",
     "android_channel_id": "noti_push_NEW_PLAY"
     "sound": "NEW_MESSAGE.wav"
 },
 "data" : {
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
    "type": "NEW_MESSAGE",
 },
 "apns": { 
    "payload": { 
        "aps": { 
            "sound": "NEW_MESSAGE.wav", 
        }   
    } 
 },
 "to" : <token>,
}
```

push notificaion does not works in IOS with error NotRegistered

```
{
    "multicast_id": <returned id>,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "NotRegistered"
        }
    ]
}
```

i don't think it is related with settings, because i can send push message to all IOS devices from firebase web console. but if i try to send it tor specific device, i can't.

i followed all step firebase setup, APN certificate, Apple id, Adding Xcode push notification capablity, etc...

what's the problem???

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've just resolved it to add

FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = YES

in info.plist

[Not Receiving push notifications from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217757/not-receiving-push-notifications-from-firebase)