# iOS Firebase Push Notification - Token received but push not working

Tags: ios, firebase, capacitor

I am currently developing an App with push notifications using Capacitor. I followed their guide for the implementation online and everything works so far. I am receiving a token & it is successfully sent to my backend. The problem I am facing right now is that when I try to send a push to that deviceToken via firebase admin SDK the push never reaches my phone (the same is true, when I try to target the whole iOS platform via Firebase Cloud Messaging).

I am not sure why I don't receive any pushes (I have tested it on 2 different devices -> both receive their pushToken, but none of the receive pushes, everything works just fine on android). Do you have any ideas what the problem might be here?

Comment: Have you asked for the permission to send notifications in the info.plist/one of the controllers Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications

Comment: Yeah I have. I pressed "Yes" upon request and after that I received the token

Comment: Do you get anything in the console when you try to push?

Comment: No unfortunately not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not Receiving push notifications from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217757/not-receiving-push-notifications-from-firebase)

Answer (score 2):

you should enable the capability of push notification and enable background mode such as:

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGZ7h.png)

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7ITq.png)

and you should go to your
firebase **project settings/cloud messaging/**
add or insert your **APNs Authentication Key**
from apple developer account

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and the solution is to delete all push notification certificates associated with the project on Apple Developer and use a key instead.